# With Oracle SQL how can I find 3 days where total sum >= 150

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a report that needs to list activity where total is >= 150 over 3 *consecutive* days.
Let's say I've created a temp table foo, to summarize daily totals.

```
| ID | Day        | Total |
| -- | ---------- | ----- |
| 01 | 2020-01-01 |   10  |
| 01 | 2020-01-02 |   50  |
| 01 | 2020-01-03 |   50  |
| 01 | 2020-01-04 |   50  |
| 01 | 2020-01-05 |   20  |
| 02 | 2020-01-01 |   10  |
| 02 | 2020-01-02 |   10  |
| 02 | 2020-01-03 |   10  |
| 02 | 2020-01-04 |   10  |
| 02 | 2020-01-05 |   10  |
```

How Would I write SQL to return ID 01, but not 02?

Example Result:

```
| ID |
| -- |
| 01 |
```

Comment: what is the output supposed to look like? Do you just want to return "01"? Or do you want to return all "01" rows? Or some of the "01" rows? Please update your question to show the expected output. And when you say "over 3 days" do you mean "any 3 days" or "over 3 consecutive days"?

Comment: Why do you expect "01" to be returned? The max sum over 3 consecutive days is 150, which is not greater than 150... unless you meant ">= 150"?

Comment: -1 you changed your question after you got a valid answer. That is absolutely objectionable here. If you realize that your question wasn't posed correctly then pose another question

Comment: @miracle173, I added Consecutive as a clarification based on comments and answers.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you want window functions here:

```
select distinct id
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        sum(total) over(partition by id order by day rows between 2 preceding and current row) sum_total,
        count(*)   over(partition by id order by day rows between 2 preceding and current row) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt = 3 and sum_total >= 150
```

This gives you the `id`s that have a total greater than the given threshold over 3 *consecutive* days - which is how I understood your question.

Comment: I think instead of `sum_total > 100` you wanted to write `and sum_total >= 150. `cnt=3` seems to be a little bi pedantic. I would assume that the OP would accept an ID if the table has only two entries for this ID but there sum is >=150. The query may report wrong results if there are mire than one entry for an ID on a day or if a DAY is missing. Actually you are showing the IDs that have sum(total) on three consecutive rows ordered by id and day. But maybe the OP can provide the data in an appropriate way.

Comment: @miracle173: thanks. I changed the threshold. For your other points, I understand what you say but it's hard to tell without more clarification from OP...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HAVING` Clause `GROUPED BY ID` to list the desired `ID` values

```
SELECT ID
  FROM foo
 GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT( distinct day )>=3 AND SUM( NVL(Total,0) ) >= 150
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b475ac4198d9576164d66e0bf6dd075f)</kbd>

Comment: Apparently your query does not  regard the fact that the days should be consecutive [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=37e5bf9c7482d91446621bc697425bc0)

Comment: Hey but original question was not this , I only realized the conversion from `> 150` to `>= 150` at the last edit. Thus, changing question's logic shouldn't be fair in this stage after two upvotes... @miracle173

Comment: I see now. You are right. The OP modified the question 30 minutes after he posted it and 25 minutes after you posted a correct solution. I cannot revoke my downvote because it is to long ago but if you edit your question I can revoke my downvote and change iit to an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to output the rows that have 3 consecutive days with a sum >= 150, you can use an analytic function to determine the moving total across each 3 day period per id, and then find the aggregate max value of the moving total per id, returning the id where it's >= 150.

E.g.:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 ID, to_date('01/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dy, 10 total FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 ID, to_date('02/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dy, 50 total FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 ID, to_date('03/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dy, 50 total FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 ID, to_date('04/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dy, 50 total FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 ID, to_date('05/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dy, 20 total FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, to_date('01/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dy, 10 total FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, to_date('02/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dy, 10 total FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, to_date('03/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dy, 10 total FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, to_date('04/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dy, 10 total FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, to_date('05/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dy, 10 total FROM dual),
    moving_sums AS (SELECT ID,
                           dy,
                           total,
                           SUM(total) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY dy RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) moving_sum
                    FROM   your_table)
SELECT ID
FROM   moving_sums
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(moving_sum) >= 150;

        ID
----------
         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you are to specify dates

```
WITH foo( ID, Day, Total ) AS
(
 SELECT '01', date'2020-01-01' ,   10  FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT '01', date'2020-01-02' ,   50  FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT '01', date'2020-01-03' ,   50  FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT '01', date'2020-01-04' ,   50  FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT '01', date'2020-01-05' ,   20  FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT '02', date'2020-01-01' ,   10  FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT '02', date'2020-01-02' ,   10  FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT '02', date'2020-01-03' ,   10  FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT '02', date'2020-01-04' ,   10  FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT '02', date'2020-01-05' ,   10  FROM dual
)SELECT
    ID
FROM foo
WHERE day BETWEEN TO_DATE('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) AND TO_DATE('2020-01-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
GROUP BY ID  HAVING SUM(Total) >= 150;
```

RESULT:

```
ID|
--|
01|
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM foo
WHERE day BETWEEN 2020-01-01 AND 2020-01-04
    AND total > 150
```

Comment: Of course he can try but the result is not related to the question he poses